# How compiler is determining which constructor to use if both take one variable of same kind (int and Integer)

Tags: java, constructor

I have a package myPackage which contains 2 classes. First one has 2 public constructors that take a numeric value. First one takes an int and the second one takes Integer. As far as I know they both are the same, just one of them is a primitive type. 
When I make an object reference in the other class and run it, in result it calls a constructor that takes the int value. 
My question: How it is determined which constructor is called in this case?
P.S. Sorry if this question is too simple. I'm just starting to learn Java.

```
package myPackage
public class myPackageClass{
 public myPackageClass(int var){
     System.out.println("Constructor + int value["+var+"]");
 }
 public myPackageClass(Integer var){
     System.out.println("Constructor + Integer value["+var+"]");
   }
}
```

the test file

```
package myPackage
public class testClass{
 public static void main(String ... arg){
    myPackageClass var2= new myPackageClass(1);
    }
  } 
}
```

and the output :" Constructor + int value[1] "

Comment: The question is simple. The answer is not. The details are in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3), but I would not suggest *reading* this now. The rule of thumb is: It picks the constructor that matches "better" (i.e. with fewer conversions). In a call with `new myPackageClass(Integer.valueOf(1))`, the `Integer`-based one would have been chosen. (This is not an answer, because I think that this can be considered as a duplicate of similar questions about *methods*, but I didn't find a good one to link to...)

Answer (score 1):

They are not exactly of the same type. `1` is of type `int`, but `new Integer(1)` would be of type `Integer`. So if you would do `new myPackageClass(new Integer(1))` the output would be `Constructor + Integer value[1]`

Other options of passing an `Integer` instead of `int` are: `new myPackageClass((Integer)1)` and `new myPackageClass(Integer.valueOf(1))`

Comment: It might be just enough to cast 1 to Integer

Comment: @rebelizant Right, that's one of the options, I added other options to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First it will lookup after one constructor with the same parameter (`myPackageClass(int)` in your case).

Then, if no constructor is found, then will lookup for one with Box/Unbox parameter ( `myPackageClass(Integer)` )

You can see the algorithm here : [jls-15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

Answer (score -2):

if you create the integer like this : Int i = new Integer(1); The second method will be invoked. If you create the integer like this Interger i = 1; if it is within range -128 ~127 the first method will be invoked else the sencond will be involed. If you use the constrctor directly like this A(1);  the first method will be invoked

Comment: if it is within range -128 ~127-> Totally bogus

Comment: my mistake. I have not tried for that. It just because  I saw an article shows that if one Integer property was defined like Integer  i = 1(within -128~127),it will be automatically unpacked to int type. But i tested just know, it doesn't work in this sence